# Kafka Connect: Getting connector configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have been testing with kafka connect. But for every connector I have to go and read the connector documentation to understand the configuration needed for the connectors. As far as I read the kafka connect API documentation I have seen to APIs to get the connector related data.

`GET /connector-plugins` - return a list of connector plugins installed in the Kafka Connect cluster. Note that the API only checks for connectors on the worker that handles the request, which means you may see inconsistent results, especially during a rolling upgrade if you add new connector jars.

`PUT /connector-plugins/{connector-type}/config/validate` - validate the provided configuration values against the configuration definition. This API performs per config validation, returns suggested values and error messages during validation.

Rest of other APIs are related to created connectors. Is there anyway to get the configuration for the required connectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway to get the configuration for the required connectors

The validate endpoint does exactly that, and is what the Landoop Kafka Connect UI uses to provide errors for missing/misconfigured properties.

The implementation details of how properties become required depends on the `Importance` level of the connector configuration, and for any non-high importance configs, referring documentation or source code (if available) would be best

Comment: I did find this out though. Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

That's an old post, but someone may still need this.

Since version 3.6 there is a way to fetch all config options for a plugin using REST API: `GET /connector-plugins/<plugin>/config`

Sadly that doesn't include recommended values that are returned in `PUT /connector-plugins/<plugin>/config/validate` endpoint.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-769%3A+Connect+APIs+to+list+all+connector+plugins+and+retrieve+their+configuration+definitions